# Django create from hash throws matching query does not exist

Tags: django, python-3.x

This has caused me to nearly tear my hair out.

I have the following model hash for the Journal table

```
db_model_fields = 
{'abbreviation': 'Olympiads Inform.',
 'issn': '18227732',
 'journal_type': 'p',
 'researcher': <Researcher: x Scopus ID r>, #actual researcher object
 'title': 'Olympiads in Informatics'}
```

When I try to save the model to the database with `Journal.objects.create(**db_model_fields)`

I get `DoesNotExist: Journal matching query does not exist.`

Which is ridiculous because the researcher definitely exists. AND when I try to save `ResearchMetrics`, another table, it works fine!

Journal Model code:

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    researcher = models.ForeignKey(Researcher,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    journal_type = models.CharField(max_length=40,default=None,blank=True, null=True)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    issn = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    journal_rank = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    properties = JSONField(default=dict)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

ResearchMetric Model Code:

```
class ResearchMetrics(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    h_index = models.IntegerField()
    co_author_count = models.IntegerField()
    citation_count = models.IntegerField()
    cited_by_count = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_subject_areas = models.IntegerField()
    document_count = models.IntegerField()
    first_publication_year = models.IntegerField()
    last_publication_year = models.IntegerField()

    number_of_journals_published_in = models.IntegerField()
    subject_area_concentration = JSONField(default=dict)
    properties = JSONField(default=dict)

    researcher = models.ForeignKey(Researcher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "ResearchMetric ID {}".format(self.id)
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this issue? it's being a huge blocker, and nowhere else in stack overflow can I find an answer to this. Thank you!

Comment: can you try to just add the researcher id the dict and not the all object and test again?

Comment: hey @Bestasttung, yeah i tried. it doesnt work :( updated question with more details

Comment: Is this in the shell or when running your code? In the latter case, what is the exact stack trace (which line is throwing the error?). Your error doesn't match the code so there must be more to this.